# My r-squared score is coming negative but my accuracy score using k-fold cross validation is coming to about 92%

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

For the code below, my r-squared score is coming out to be negative but my accuracies score using k-fold cross validation is coming out to be 92%. How's this possible? Im using random forest regression algorithm to predict some data. The link to the dataset is given in the link below:
https://www.kaggle.com/ludobenistant/hr-analytics

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder

dataset = pd.read_csv("HR_comma_sep.csv")
x = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values   ##Independent variable
y = dataset.iloc[:,9].values     ##Dependent variable

##Encoding the categorical variables

le_x1 = LabelEncoder()
x[:,7] = le_x1.fit_transform(x[:,7])
le_x2 = LabelEncoder()
x[:,8] = le_x1.fit_transform(x[:,8])
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [7,8])
x = ohe.fit_transform(x).toarray()


##splitting the dataset in training and testing data

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
y = pd.factorize(dataset['left'].values)[0].reshape(-1, 1)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_x = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc_x.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc_x.transform(x_test)
sc_y = StandardScaler()
y_train = sc_y.fit_transform(y_train)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10, random_state = 0)
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(x_test)
print(y_pred)
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score(y_test , y_pred)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = regressor, X = x_train, y = y_train, cv = 10)
accuracies.mean()
accuracies.std()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several issues with your question...

For starters, you are doing a very basic mistake: you *think* you are using accuracy as a metric, while you are in a regression setting and the actual metric used underneath is the [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) (MSE).

Accuracy is a metric used in *classification*, and it has to do with the percentage of the correctly classified examples - check the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) entry for more details.

The metric used internally in your chosen regressor (Random Forest) is included in the verbose output of your `regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)` command - notice the `criterion='mse'` argument:

```python
RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=True, criterion='mse', max_depth=None,
           max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
           min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
           min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
           n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=0,
           verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

MSE is a positive continuous quantity, and it is not upper-bounded by 1, i.e. if you got a value of 0.92, this means... well, 0.92, and *not* 92%.

Knowing that, it is good practice to include explicitly the MSE as the scoring function of your cross-validation:

```python
cv_mse = cross_val_score(estimator = regressor, X = x_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
cv_mse.mean()
# -2.433430574463703e-28
```

For all practical purposes, this is zero - you fit the *training* set almost perfectly; for confirmation, here is the (perfect again) R-squared score on your *training* set:

```python
train_pred = regressor.predict(x_train)
r2_score(y_train , train_pred)
# 1.0
```

But, as always, the moment of truth comes when you apply your model on the *test* set; your **second** mistake here is that, since you train your regressor with scaled `y_train`, you should also scale `y_test` before evaluating:

```python
y_test = sc_y.transform(y_test)
r2_score(y_test , y_pred)
# 0.9998476914664215
```

and you get a very nice R-squared in the *test* set (close to 1).

What about the MSE?

```python
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
mse_test
# 0.00015230853357849051
```

Comment: Thanks on the above. If a cross validation mean squared error cv_mse.mean() returns a value of -10 can I consider the model as a well trained model?

Comment: @Coder MSE and similar metrics values depend on the *scale* of the data; contrary to the accuracy in classification, you cannot say that a value is "good" or "bad" in itself.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `y_test = sc_y.transform(y_test)` in order to reuse the scaler that was fit on `y_train`? With `y_test = sc_y.fit_transform(y_test)`, you are creating new scalers for `y_train` and `y_test` whereas with `x_` the scaler was reused [`x_train = sc_x.fit_transform(x_train); x_test = sc_x.transform(x_test)`].

Comment: @There indeed this was a typo from my part (just corrected it), and I can't believe it had stayed here for 6 years w/o anyone noticing; thanks for pointing it out ;)