# How to calculate percent of error in keras

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I use keras and set machine learning model to predict my data like this.

```
K.clear_session()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500,
          batch_size=2, verbose=1,
          )
```

Output after model.fit show loss such as ***loss: 0.0382***.  I don't know what is mean ***loss: 0.0382***. How many percent of error between train and test data ? How to calculate ?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what do you mean by percentage?

Comment: My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864926/my-r-squared-score-is-coming-negative-but-my-accuracy-score-using-k-fold-cross-v/46887354#46887354) may help clarifying things; it's in a different context (`scikit-learn`), but your question is on a very elementary level, independently of any specific packages & implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `mean_squared_error` (mse) loss function.

The MSE assesses the quality of an estimator (i.e., a mathematical function mapping a sample of data to a parameter of the population from which the data is sampled) or a predictor (i.e., a function mapping arbitrary inputs to a sample of values of some random variable).

[Formula for MSE](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/67b9ac7353c6a2710e35180238efe54faf4d9c15)

**MSE** must be low for a good model. Lower the MSE better the model.

In your training you got a loss of `0.0382`. Which is pretty good.

In `Keras` there is another loss function named `mean_absolute_percentage_error`. You can compile the model with `mean_absolute_percentage_error` as loss function if you want to know the percentage error of the model with train and test.

If you want to evaluate the model after compilation and training based on how much Accuracy the model has, you can use `evaluate()` function like this.

```
scores = model.evaluate(X_validation, Y_validation, verbose=1)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: I use model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error', optimizer='adam'). Why output is    
Epoch 200/200
39/39 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 74374.4342   

Is it more than 100% ? How to use it?

Comment: I have edited the answer. I think finding the accuracy of the model is what you are looking for.